# Hide Navigation bar for cordova app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I want to hide navigation bar in my app cordova android app. I'm using cordova navigation bar plugin but it hides navigation bar at index page, I want to hide navigation bar from splash screen i.e created by using splash screen plugin.

Kindly suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide us some example code of what you did, that's going to only help us and you. Read about what you (shouldn't ask)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask] and (MCV)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Comment: use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar plugin

Answer (score 5):

Just edit in Android Studio conifg.xml (app -> res -> xml -> config.xml), just add `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />` and run your app!

Comment: Where inside config.xml do I put it?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to install this plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config

Installation:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

If using Cordova version => 6.2.0 use:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config --fetch
```

Then you can edit the Android theme by editing your config.xml

```
<preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:theme" value="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

This should hide the navigation bar and give you a full screen experience.